# Docker + Swift + Passing Arguments

Tags: swift, docker, parameter-passing

Can anyone help on how to pass arguments through Docker to a Swift project?

This is the class that I have for Swift:

```
import Foundation


print("Hello, world!")


// There is always one argument passed, which is the name of the program,
// that is the file name.
if CommandLine.argc < 2 {

    print("No arguments are passed.")
    let firstArgument = CommandLine.arguments[0]
    print(firstArgument)
} else {

    print("Arguments are passed.")
    let arguments = CommandLine.arguments
    for argument in arguments {
        print(argument)
    }
}
```

This is the commands that I run:

```
docker build -t my-swift-image . 
docker run --rm my-swift-image
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM swift
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
CMD swift package clean
CMD swift run
```

Folder Structure

```
- app
   - Sources
      - SuiteTest
         - main.swift
```

app/Sources/SuiteTest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
docker run --rm -it my-swift-image arg1 arg2
```

to add the arguments to the commandline. This works in a setup like this

Dockerfile:

```
FROM swift
COPY . /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ENTRYPOINT ["swift", "run", "myapp"]
```

image built & run using

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker run --rm -it myapp arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Hi @gereon thank you for your answer but when I run that this is what I got:
docker run --rm -it my-swift-image aaaaa bbbbb ccccc
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused "exec: \"aaaaa\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

Comment: Please show your `Dockerfile`. How are you defining the ENTRYPOINT?

Comment: @Gereon I updated the question to add the dockerfile, I was unaware of the ENTRYPOINT field I did test to add in last line dockerfile ENTRYPOINT ./app/Sources/SuiteTest/ and i got this error aaaaa: 1: aaaaa: ./app/Sources/SuiteTest/: not found but if I enter the docker I can see that the folder is there

Comment: Updated my answer.